# Unity shader error; presumably in if statement

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am doing two line plane intersections in a shader, however I need to take account if a ray was not hit and which one of the rays has the shortest distance.

The following code however throws an error which doesn't give me any useful information (and points me in the wrong direction). If I set tex and selectN to say intersection.xy and N, it works fine (but ofcourse doesn't give the result I need).

I'm working in Unity.

```
float3 selectN;

float2 tex;
if (dist == 0.0) {
   selectN = N2;
   tex = intersection2.xy;
} else if (dist2 == 0.0) {
   selectN = N;
   tex = intersection.xy;
} else if (dist < dist2) {
   selectN = N;
   tex = intersection.xy;
} else {
   selectN = N2;
   tex = intersection2.xy;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add #pragma target 3.0 because my shader was getting "too complex".

Comment: I'm unexperienced with shaders and found your question pretty intersting. Could you post some more details about this #pragma mark, or just a link to documentation?